# naked tabularray's longtblr? (just the contents)

Tags: longtblr

I was reading through longtblr documentation, going through forums etc, but got somehow lost between themes, templates for various things etc. Could I get a minimal example of writing a "naked" longtblr, i.e. without caption and title, without continuation headers/footers (and also without redefining default templates, so that other tables are not affected), effectively giving lines with identical horizontal alignment or items?

For the sake of learning, I would appreciate one version where all the settings are inline (if this is possible), and one defining a new environment (perhaps `nakedlongtblr`) which will already contain all those settings.

**EDIT:**

This is the result when everything is left out:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtblr}{}
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
        ...
    \end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Captions, headers and footers are optional. Just leave them out.

Comment: I added a screenshot when everything is empty, marking the things I would like to go away in red.

Comment: Oh! `longtblr`! I read `longtable`: use this one instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new theme for naked tables:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\NewTblrTheme{naked}{
  \DefTblrTemplate{foot}{empty}{}
  \SetTblrTemplate{foot}{empty}
  \DefTblrTemplate{head}{empty}{}
  \SetTblrTemplate{head}{empty}
}


\begin{document}
    \begin{longtblr}[theme=naked]{}
      a & b \\
      a & b \\
      a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        a & b \\
      a & b \\        
    \end{longtblr}
    
    \begin{longtblr}{}
        a & b \\
        a & b \\
    \end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to do naked table also without using themes/templates, just by setting the outer/inner options?